# What is good way to validates Canadian Postal Code in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on Rails 4 app, and need to validates against Canadian Post Code such as "B1C 2B3" as part of user address.

I have found this gem https://github.com/globaldev/going_postal but i think it's over kill just for validation.

Is there another way to write validation for Post Code?

Comment: Can you describe a pattern (possibly regular expression) for valid Canadian postal code. Any edge case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [on debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AAarm-b8H4RWIGKm) (a great regex testing site) that the canadian postal code regex is

```
[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}[ -]?\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}
```

To check a string against that pattern, do the following for your validation:

```
CANADIAN_POSTAL_CODE_FORMAT = /\A[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}[ -]?\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}\z/
validates :postal_code, format: { with: CANADIAN_POSTAL_CODE_FORMAT }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tested with rails 4.2. Also: http://rubular.com/r/m6pe3FUi0s

Answer (score 4):

I understand you ask for a oneliner instead of adding a gem, but just in case others consider that option, you can use **[`validates_zipcode`](http://github.com/dgilperez/validates_zipcode)** gem I wrote. It currently supports **259 countries** postal code formats, most of them taken from [CLDR database](http://cldr.unicode.org/)  and plays nice with Rails 3 & 4. It does have support for Canada :)

You can use it like this:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_zipcode :zipcode
  # or
  validates :zipcode, zipcode: { country_code_attribute: :postal_code }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the validation should be (all single slashes, no double): `/\A[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}[ -]?\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}\z/`